# how to convert react/vue.js events in amp

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, amp-html

If my project `UI` content `react/vue.js` and I want to create amp page after added all `amp-boilerplate`.

it is not working with the event it gives error likes below

> The attribute 'v-on:click' may not appear in tag 'li'. The attribute 'v-show' may not appear in tag 'ul'.

please let me know how to convert it.

Comment: Can you add any details like code used? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use amp-bind which is allows you to add custom stateful interactivity to your AMP pages & amp-state

on="tap:AMP.setState({'abc': 'xyz'})"